# What to do with domain specific words and phrases in foreign language?

Tags: coding-style

Even though I'm not a native English speaker, I try to keep my code written in English as much as possible. When in a project where domain specific words and phrases are non-English, I often find myself pulled between translating the word and just using the non-English word in my code (variables, method names, class names etc.).

Translating the word would make the code read more like plain English, with the downside of confusing someone who is accustomed to the non-English word/phrase. **Not** translating gives you awkward looking names, but they are easier to understand for those familiar with the domain. Aesthetically it makes me cringe a little.

An example of the latter would be something like `getVirksomhet()` where the Norwegian word "virksomhet" translates to something like "business unit" in English, but also has a special connotation in this particular project.

What do you do, and what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: We ended up with a 'VultureBasement' as field in the database where a liquid manure pit was meant. (in dutch: Gierkelder, gier=>Vulture, kelder=>Basement). At least have a glosary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked several years with the most funny translations (from Dutch to English) doing exactly the same that you do: stick as much as possible to English.

However, it creates more confusion than being really usefull (Not to mention the fact that you have to actively manage the "correct translation" otherwise all kinds of minor variations might show up in local variables, counters etc.).

So unless you have some plans to offshore your development soon, I would stick to getVirksomhet() because you all know what it means.

I also worked with some non-native-Dutch programmers andthey had no problems whatsoever in working with the Dutch equivalent of getVirksomhet() etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ask if you still keep everything else in your code in English? To me this makes the most sense. Translating common patterns like prefixing getters with "get", setters with "set", naming a factory <something>Factory etc. I feel will just throw people off track.

Comment: Yes, for Get Set and things like that it gets more complicated the other way around. If we would translate these to dutch (Haal..) it would be very weird. We did have some discussion about code comments: dutch or english and decided on english in the end

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how ubiquitous the term is.  If you are developing the system in Norway, and all of the business people and development staff will know Virksomhet, then I would use the business term -- especially because it has nuances above its English translation.

If the term will not be well-understood by the development staff, then you might end up with an impediment to understanding -- which is what ubiquitous language seeks to avoid.  In that case, you have to either document the heck out of the term in your code, or work with the business people to come up with an acceptable replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer depends on the cultural environment and your target group. I am Greek and I have working experience in UK, Greece and France. I noticed that my own answer to the question was different each time:

UK: English, of course.

Greece: All terms translated in English. Most Greek programmers are familiar with the English terms. Besides, a good deal of programming languages don't accept Greek characters for identifiers and the use of the Latin alphabet to write Greek is non standard and ugly.

France: Well, French written without accents. Most of the times it looks like inverted English, ie "getApplicationCourante" instead of "getCurrentApplication". This has a nice side effect: in an alphabetical sorting, the methods will be grouped by the noun which is usually more important than the adjective. Still, the unavoidable mix of the two languages looks ugly, but this is really better than having French people use English :-P

Having said that, you have to make sure that your target group is also familiar with the language. While working on SAP with ABAP, I really disliked the fact that many functions and database fields where in German. It's even worse if you consider than the keywords of ABAP, which is also created by SAP, are all in English...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should talk to your clients, and try to work out an english translation of the important domain concepts that you can both agree on and that is documented. If you're lucky, they may already have this.